# ViewPager2 | Different fragment widths

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I want to make ViewPager2 with two fragments with different width, but with the same start and end margins. The width of **first** fragment is `match_parent` with a **56dp** end-margin.
The width of **second** fragment is **256dp**.

This is the result I get with the code below

[image: Result I get]

**XML**

`<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 android:id="@+id/viewPager2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

**Kotlin**

`binding.viewPager2.clipToPadding = false binding.viewPager2.clipChildren = false binding.viewPager2.setPadding(getDpValue(16), 0, getDpValue(56), 0) binding.viewPager2.setPageTransformer(MarginPageTransformer(getDpValue(16)))`

And finally, this is the result I want (here I'm holding ViewPager2 without swiping it)

[image]